# TextField with Label over the border at Top-Left position

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, material-components-ios

I need to implement outline textfield with placeholder in my swift project one like the Material UI. I tried googling for the same but could not found anything. Anyone know how to achieve it in swift?
Reference Images:

[image]

[image: uit]

Comment: Somthing like this? https://github.com/raginmari/RAGTextField

Comment: @AndreasOetjen yes but not exactly, is has type outline which is out of textfield border.

Comment: you can check this:https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios and use `pod 'MaterialComponents/TextFields'` and `pod 'MaterialComponents/TextFields+ColorThemer'`

Comment: Something like this? https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/tree/stable/components/TextFields/styling

Comment: That can only be achieved by programmatically right? I mean to not from the `Storyboard`.

Comment: It is android style, don't do it on iOS :) Prefer native solution :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using this [pod](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios), you can get the same design

1. Take `UIView` on Storyboard and set constraints
2. Make class which is a subclass of `UIView` and import pods `MaterialComponents.MaterialTextFields` and `MaterialComponents.MaterialTextFields_ColorThemer`

class CustomOutlinedTxtField: UIView {

```
private var textFieldControllerFloating: MDCTextInputControllerOutlined!
var textField: MDCTextField!

@IBInspectable var placeHolder: String!
@IBInspectable var value: String!
@IBInspectable var primaryColor: UIColor! = .purple

override open func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    textField.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)

}
open override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    setUpProperty()
}
func setUpProperty() {
    //Change this properties to change the propperties of text
    textField = MDCTextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height))
    textField.placeholder = placeHolder
    textField.text = value

    //Change this properties to change the colors of border around text
    textFieldControllerFloating = MDCTextInputControllerOutlined(textInput: textField)

    textFieldControllerFloating.activeColor = primaryColor
    textFieldControllerFloating.floatingPlaceholderActiveColor = primaryColor
    textFieldControllerFloating.normalColor = UIColor.lightGray
    textFieldControllerFloating.inlinePlaceholderColor = UIColor.lightGray

    //Change this font to make borderRect bigger
    textFieldControllerFloating.inlinePlaceholderFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
    textFieldControllerFloating.textInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))

    self.addSubview(textField)
}
```

}

3. Assign that custom class to `UIView`

[image]

**Result**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks promising, will give it a shot and come back. Thanks :)

Comment: is it working for you?

Comment: Yes, thanks it is working.

Comment: Hey, how can I change the height of textfield? I tried but not able to do that.

Comment: You are assigning a custom class to view, from storyboard you can change the height

Comment: Yes I tried from storyboard but it is always bigger

Comment: For reference see the mobile no field: https://prnt.sc/r77m5f and view hierarchy: https://prnt.sc/r77mhw

Comment: Please check comment in the answer above line `textFieldControllerFloating.inlinePlaceholderFont` and see last comments https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/issues/6253

Comment: Yes I have checked that, is there any other way I can set height of the textfield and keeping the same placeholder font?

Comment: Sorry, currently I don't know any other way

Comment: Do you know why the constraints of the other components do not work when we add this pod's custom textfield? The components look ok with the constraints in the storyboard but when the app is running on the device, the text fields overlap the other components.

Comment: Sorry, but without seeing code I'm not able to say anything about this

Answer (score 1):

> You can use Material Components:-

It will be looking like this below.

https://material.io/components/text-fields/
[image]

Github repo - https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios

Comment: @niraj You can follow this github repo and you can find this exact solution

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this framework `SkyFloatingLabelTextField` , `TextFieldEffects` or `TweeTextField`

https://github.com/Skyscanner/SkyFloatingLabelTextField

https://github.com/oleghnidets/TweeTextField

https://github.com/raulriera/TextFieldEffects